# Forcing the Android emulator to store changes to /system

Tags: android, emulation

I know this is a recurrent question when working with the Android emulator, but is there a way to force the emulator to accept persistent changes to `/system`?

The emulator is based on QEMU, so it should be possible, in theory, to force the `system` image to behave the same way `userdata` (for instance) does, but I'm not familiar with how QEMU handles things. Any pointers?

Comment: Actually, even the local system image (in my AVD directory) is _not_ persisted in the most recent versions of the emulator... Unless I did something wrong?

Comment: See Yury's answer about that, then maybe mine for an alternative way (found this just yesterday). You can use `adb remount` to make changes to `/system`, but they are not persisted if you restart the emulator, which is what I need.

Comment: Thanks! The blog where I originally found a solution was shut down recently. I definitely needed a new reference. ;)

Comment: see just this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/58935109/4797289

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At the moment (with Build Tools v26, if Google doesn't change things as often as they do) if you use the `-writable-system` directive while booting up the emulator from the command line, it will allow persistence to the `/system` partition through reboots. That is you will be able to write to the `/system` partition and if you reboot, the changes will still be maintained.

`emulator -avd <AVD_NAME> -writable-system`

This will also persist your changes to a `qcow2` image file usually in `.android/avd/<AVD_NAME>.avd/system.img.qcow2`

You can even copy this `system.img.qcow2` file, wipe the data off the AVD using the `-wipe-data` directive, place this file back into the directory, reboot and the system changes you made initially will still be persisted. (Caveat: at least for now, coz Google keeps changing things)

Comment: Thanks for keeping this up to date :)

Comment: the files remain changed, but the root is not active. Do you have a solution for permanent root with latest build-tools?

Comment: `-wipe-data` invalid command, also how to resize system partition? `-partition-size` also doesn't work, says invalid command (removed?)

Comment: This works, but note that it writes to a separated qcow2 file instead of to the `.img` directly: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110927/how-to-mount-system-rewritable-or-read-only-rw-ro/207200#207200

Comment: important note: you need to *keep using `-writable-system`* to see your previous persistent changes. omitting `-writable-system` will use the default system image, without your changes.

Answer (score 15):

**Update:** The `-nand` option was apparently removed from the most recent versions of QEMU, so the following may not work anymore.

**Update:** See the accepted answer for the current way of doing things.

---

Yury's answer is the common one, but if you want to be able to script things (which is what I want in the end), you need to be able to find the emulator image in the `/tmp` directory.

I discovered that you can override QEMU's behavior. This is a bit hackish, but it works, so I ended up doing this :

1. Copy `system.img` from the platform directory to your AVD directory.
2. Convert the amount of space you need to hex. For instance, if you need 500M, this is `0x1f400000`.
3. Run the emulator in read-write mode :

   ```
   emulator -avd Galaxy_Nexus -qemu -nand system,size=0x1f400000,file=/home/fx/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus/system.img
   ```

   *(If you put the emulator in verbose mode, you'll notice that it will, by default, use `initfile=` instead of just `file=`)*
4. Make your changes, they are immediately saved to the local `system.img`
5. Now you can just start the emulator with `emulator -avd Galaxy_Nexus`, and it'll use your changes

***Update:** If scripting, QEMU does not sync changes immediately to the image, so if you're rebooting immediately after changing something, chances are you will lose data. I'm looking for a way around this...*

***Next update:** Use `adb -e emu kill` to stop the emulator. `reboot` will just do bad things.*

Comment: Hey man, this was a really amazing tip! Didn't knew at all, that it's possible to start the emulator in a read/write mode. Until now I've tried around with yaff2 to dynamically create images, but your answer made things much more easier. I'm using your mechanism now in the latest version of my [Scala Libs for android installation script](https://github.com/svenwiegand/scala-libs-for-android-emulator). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks! It's too bad the Android team didn't add an option for that, instead of having to do some crazy stuff with obscure QEMU options... (By the way, I set the accepted answer to mine since we're using it in the latest `sbt-android` plugin, it works really well for setting up the emulator in one easy step!)

Comment: `qemu-system-x86_64: -nand: invalid option` — that means they removed support for doing that?

Comment: where did you find those commands? `system,size=0x1f400000` I tried to change system partition size using `-partition-size` command from https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#startup-options but it doesn't work anymore (and they don't update information on their site)...

Comment: and this value in bytes? 0x1f400000, 524288000 == 500mb, right?

Comment: I found them mostly by skimming the qemu manual for interesting bits. It's kind of a long read though :)

Answer (score 8):

It's actually a very good question. I had the same troubles. Here are my findings. Actually, I use Ubuntu and I'll describe the steps for Ubuntu. If you use Windows, you should just change the paths.

1. Create new AVD, for instance `example.avd`
2. Copy system.img from `android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-10/images`
   to `~/.android/avd/example.avd`
3. Make system.img as writable and readable (either in the properties
   or simply using terminal)
4. Run your AVD using command `emulator -avd example`
5. Remount your system as rw using adb shell `mount -o rw,remount -t
   yaffs2 /dev/block/mtd0 /system` (to discover the partition use
   command `cat /proc/mtd`)
6. Make your changes...
7. Now during the run of emulator find tmp emulator in
   `/tmp/android-<your_computer_name>` with strange name like:
   `emulator-PQ7LgE` and copy it in `~/.android/avd/example.avd`
8. Delete `system.img` and rename copied tmp emulator into `system.img`
9. Close emulator
10. Delete `cache.img`, `userdata.img` and `userdata-qemu.img` from
     `~/.android/avd/example.avd`
11. Run your emulator once again

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, now I don't know which one to choose from ;)

Comment: -1 'Make system.img as writable and readable (either in the properties or simply using terminal)' more details are needed ...

Answer (score 2):

The solution #2 is amazing.

Here are some hints if you are using MS Win as host
AVD directories are located as below, but the "short" path names should be used
as file= path parameter. The quoted path variant doesn't work for some reason.

Win XP:  C:\Documents and Settings\ (username) \ .android\avd\ ...
Short    C:\DOCUME~1\ (username) \ANDROI~1\avd\ ...

Win 7    C:\Users\ (username) \ .android\avd\ ...

You can create an own bat file, say "startrw.bat" as per following example:

```
@echo off
C:\<ADTFOLDER>\sdk\tools\emulator -avd <AVDNAME> -qemu -nand system,size=0x1f400000,file=C:\DOCUME~1\<USERNAME>\ANDROI~1\avd\<AVDNAME>.AVD\system.img
cd C:\<ADTFOLDER>\sdk\platform-tools
echo .
echo Wait ... 
echo .
echo When emulator is FULLY loaded press any key to connect adb shell to it
echo To make /system writeable type in adb shell:
echo .
echo -----------------------------
echo mount -o rw,remount /system 
echo -----------------------------
echo .
echo You can use the Eclipse ADT DDMS File Browser to browse or push-pull files now.
echo .
echo Closing this window closes the emulator ! 
echo .
echo Wait emulator to load Android. When done
pause
C:\<ADTFOLDER>\sdk\platform-tools\adb shell
```

This way you can load in one click. 
Once finished modifying, just close the current command window to kill the emulator.

It takes long time for most of things to load like Emulator, the ADT editor, Hooking DDMS file browser (you need to click on the emulator line left side to see the files tree on right window) and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble finding the system.img file and AVD directory that F.X. posted about. On Mac you can find them here:

- system.img: `~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-19/default/`
- AVD Directory: `~/.android/avd/Nexus.avd/`

I don't have enough reputation to add it as a comment, so I had to post it like this. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

use this command in terminal

```
cd /Users/NAME_USER/Library/Android/sdk/emulator # Move to emulator folder
sudo ./emulator -writable-system -avd NAME_AVD -partition-size 280 # Run avd by writable system 
sudo adb root # Change to root
sudo adb remount # remount again
sudo adb shell 
su
mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

change NAME_USER and NAME_AVD

Comment: Does not work. `adbd cannot run as root in production builds`.

Answer (score 0):

F.X.'s answer does not work for me with Android API 19 and 21 on Windows as it stands. With the given parameters

```
emulator -avd <AVD> -qemu -nand system,size=0x<SIZE IN HEX>,file=<PATH/TO/system.img>
```

the system fails to mount the image. By looking at the kernel output I found out that it uses suspicious page size (2048) and two nonzero parameter values: extra size and "erase". These parameters are not documented anywhere, but you can see them in [qemu's source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/master/hw/android/goldfish/nand.c). What ended up working for me was

```
emulator -avd <AVD> -qemu -nand system,size=0x<SIZE IN HEX>,file=<PATH/TO/system.img>,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
```

With those parameters specified, "erase" gets set to 0 as well.

I was also surprised to find out that with these parameters the system is unable to boot to the graphical environment, but adb works.

Comment: where did you find those commands (like `system,size`) where is it documented?

Comment: value should be in bytes or megabytes?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the following command:

```
<path-to-emulator-executable> -avd <AVD> -partition-size 512
```

Comment: you may need to do `./emulator` or `emulator-x86`. Basically replace `emulator` with the path to your emulator executable file.

Answer (score 0):

As said here at https://justus.berlin/2015/02/make-persistent-changes-to-system-in-android-emulator/
Copying system.img into avd folder will work.

Answer (score -1):

> New year new solutions.

Just copy the system.img to your avd folder and rename the system.img to system-qemu.img

For me, copying `C:\Android\sdk\system-images\android-22\android-tv\armeabi-v7a\system.img`
to `C:\Users\Neil Agarwal\.android\avd\Android_TV_1080p_API_22.avd\`
and **renaming it to system-qemu.img** did the trick.

Please restart your avd after this.